# What is the supported method for enabling/disabling services on elementary OS?

Tags: boot

I installed the `openssh-server` package but only want it to start on demand, as opposed to boot which is the package default.

When I tried to disable the SSH server using upstart I got the following output and warning

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh disable
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match ssh 
Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/ssh do not exist.
```

Is this something to be concerned about? Should I be using another method? Best I can tell Freya is based on Ubuntu 14.04 which was still using upstart as the service management system.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ssh, it's ssh**d**.

`sudo service sshd disable`

Comment: On most systems you'd be correct about that, but apparently this is not the case on eOS    seth@mm ~> service ssh status
    ssh stop/waiting
    seth@mm ~> service sshd status
    sshd: unrecognized service.  Also this does not address the broader question at hand